# Convert sqlite3 timestamp to epoch time in python

Tags: python, datetime, sqlite, epoch

I would like to convert the datetime I select from my sqlite3 database into unixepoch. An easy way would be, I guess, to insert timestamps in my database in unixepoch, but I would rather not, since it makes my database less readable.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor() 
c.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists table_name (datetime text, column1 real, column2 real)')
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime'),?,?)", data)
c.execute("SELECT datetime from table_name")

#here I would like to convert the above selection (datetime in localtime) to unixepoch
```

Thank you for reading this!

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlite3` database **already** comes with an adapter to interpret ISO date-time formats as [`datetime.datetime()` objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime):

```
c.execute('SELECT datetime as "datetime [timestamp]" from table_name')
for datetime, in c:
    print type(datetime)
```

This will print `<type 'datetime.datetime'>` for each row. `datetime.datetime()` objects are far more flexible and powerful than UNIX epoch offsets.

Note the `as "datetime [timestamp]"` alias; this adds type information to the column overriding the `text` type for that column in the `CREATE TABLE` definition, allowing Python to apply the type adapter. If you declare your column as `timestamp` you don't even have to make your query use an alias:

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists table_name (datetime timestamp, column1 real, column2 real)')
```

If you *have* to use UNIX epoch offsets, you can convert them with the [`time.mktime()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) and the [`datetime.datetime.timetuple()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple):

```
timeoffset = time.mktime(datetime.timetuple())
```